# connecting with WCF client

Tags: wcf, tcp, webservices-client

I am trying to connect to a Java based service from WCF .NET client.
the address of the service is something like https://xxxxx:4444/myownservice
I can successfully access the WSDL on 
https://servername:4444/myownservice/?WSDl
but when I run the proxy client , the process is timing out and gave me this error message

"Could not connect to ..... TCP error code 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xxxxx:4444

where xxxx is the server name

I tried to telnet the server with the port number, and telnet failed (using server name or its IP address).
I can ping to the server.

My question is: 
if I can browser the wsdl with
http://xxxxx:4444/servicename/?WSDL
does it mean that the port 4444 is open?
or not necessarily

Comment: Hello, do you use http proxy in your browser? You can also install Network monitor and check the difference between calling from browser and from your application.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the service was up and running when you grabbed the WSDL, but that it dropped thereafter.  Since you can't telnet to it, I'd say the service is down.  Since you can ping it, I'd say the server itself is running.  Ping operates on a different port.

Comment: My question is
If I can browse the WSDL from 
http://servername:4444/service/?WSDL
does that mean , the port 4444 is open?
Because when I use telnet , it fails
I use telnet with this command

telnet servername 4444